# Am I counting wrong? Why does the space of Skew-Hermitian have $n^2- 1$ elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \{ B : B = -B^* \}$ be the set of skew-hermitiain matrices with square $n \times n$ $B$ matrices. This is also the Lie Algebra of $SU(n)$.

So this is how I am counting.

Since it is skew-hermitian $b_{ij} = -b_{ij}^* = -\overline{b_{ji}}$. This means one triangle is completely determined and so the diagonal.

So $n^2 - n$ denotes the dimension of the matrix subtracting the diagonal of $n$ leaving us with 2 triangles. But since one side has been determined, we divide by $2$. Shouldn't the Lie Algebra and Lie Group have the same dimension?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a dimension over $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb C$.  For each $b_{ij}$ above the diagonal you have two real dimensions, e.g. the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I don't get it, how does that make the diagonal $n$ disappear and $1$ appear?

Comment: $n$ diagonal entires, each contributing $1$ to the dimension.  $(n^2-n)/2$ off-diagonal entries, each contributing $2$.  $1 \cdot n + 2 \cdot (n^2-n)/2 = n^2$.

Comment: For $su(n)$ you have an additional constraint, that the trace is $0$.  That knocks the dimension down to $n^2-1$.